# unable to execute the ruby Watir script, empty browser instance is opened and the below error is thrown

Tags: ruby, watir

unable to execute the ruby Watir script, empty browser instance is opened and the below error is thrown.

- ERROR:

  `C:\watir>ruby DevStageCompareNew.rb
  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in 
  initialize: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::
  ECONNREFUSED)
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in open
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in block in connect
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in timeout
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in connect
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in do_start
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in start
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in request
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in response_for
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in request
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in call
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in raw_execute
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:101:in create_session
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in initialize
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:29:in initialize
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in new
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in for
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in for
          from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.7.0/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in initialize
          from DevStageCompareNew.rb:4:in new
          from DevStageCompareNew.rb:4:in <main>`

can someone help to resolve this..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add the contents of your Ruby script? (not as a comment, but by editing your question)

Comment: Seems like either your browser automation port is blocked, or the browser version uses a different port than the automation driver. You should provide more information about that.

Comment: I have resolved it by degrading the ruby version